# Does starting an AsyncTask inside onResume method does cost more memory?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I use `AsyncTask` to update list from  local database(sqlite)  as the following :

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       new MyAsynctask().execute();

    }
```

I need a clear explanation what happen every time when new MyAsynctask execute and what happen to the previous MyAsynctask that was created earlier, and if this way cost more memory?

Comment: Problem is: everytime onResume gets called in your Activity a new MyAsynctask is created and executed. Huge memory leak :o. You have to stop it yourself and recreate it!

Comment: give me please the best practices to stop MyAsynctask and reacreat it

Comment: @ReneFerrari How do you figure that this is a (huge) memory leak? As soon as the asynctask ends, it is cleaned up

Comment: I think he mean `OutOfMemory` rather than Memory Leak.

Comment: Memory leak to me defines as something which you did not expect is still running and consuming memory. Problem in your case is if onResume() is called many times many AsyncTasks are running in parallel. Therefore the memory consumption goes up a lot and could as Enzokie mentioned lead to an OutOfMemory. ADM already wrote an answer explaining how you can avoid this :)

Answer (score 1):

Your new async task does nothing.

AsyncTasks are executed after each other.

Only when your old async task ends the new one will start running.

Comment: when async task dies??

Comment: An ayct task ends when doInBackground() ends and after that onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is just a implementation of thread to manage Background task and UI updation . `AsyncTask` is designed to be a helper class around `Thread` and `Handler` in android .From the documentation .

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

So for your question each time you call `new MyAsynctask().execute();` A new thread will starts . And the older one will run also if not finished .

To cancel previous task you can use a global instance of task and check if status is RUNNING by `getStatus()`

```
 if(asyncTask!=null && asyncTask.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
            asyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
```

In your case you create new task in `onResume()` so each time your activity resumes new thread will created and this is not memory efficient solution to refresh screen.
For more detail on cancel task read Section [Cancelling a task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [cancel(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)).

Comment: unfortunately if  the `Activity` is re-created,  the `AsyncTask` instance will be re-created as well. If you then check the status it will be relative to the new `asyncTask` instance, not the old one (which may still be running). I think he's better off by manually stopping the `task` in `onPause()`.

Comment: I did not say That . I only imply that how to check status . It depends upon the implementation and involvement if Activity's  lifecycle .

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to manage it, then it's not a memory leak.

Your `AsyncTask` will be executed inside the `onResume()` function, thus it will run when:

1. Every-time the `Activity` is (re)created
2. You come back from another `Activity`
3. You change screen orientantion
4. You come back from another `Application` started by an `Intent`
5. You close and re-open your `App`
6. ...

You might want to keep a class field for your `AsyncTask` and instantiate it in `onCreate()`:

```
private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;
```

In case the `Activty`is not destroyed (points: 1, 2 (maybe), 4(maybe), 5(maybe)), you can easily check the `asyncTask` status and cancel it if needed.

The problem is that the old `AsyncTask` might still be running when you start a new one if the `Activity` was re-created. And since the `Activity` instance is new, the `asyncTask` reference **will point to a new Object as well**: in that case you will have a savage `Thread` running in the background.

Unless `Android`'s OS kills `Activity`'s owned `Thread` *(not sure about that)*, you might still get away by knowing and **making sure** that your `AsyncTask` will run for a few seconds at most, without performing any blocking IO operation. But this isn't really an engineered solution.

---

I'd say, the **best and more standard-compliant** solution is: by keeping the reference to the `AsyncTask` in your `Activity`, just call `asyncTask.cancel()` in your `onPause()` method. And you'll be sure that the `AsyncTask`'s thread will be canceled before your `Activity` is either paused or destroyed.

Your code will then look like this:

```
private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;

protected void onCreate() {
    this.asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
}

protected void onResume() {
    this.asyncTask.execute();
}

protected void onPause() {
    this.asyncTask.cancel();
}
```